# Redirecting to a new page with href vs replace

Tags: javascript, html

While redirecting to a new page using JS - when to use `location.replace()` and when `location.href`. From [MDN replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) I get that history won't be stored if we use `location.replace`. But what are the scenarios when I should be doing this?

Also from what I understand `window.location` and `window.location.href` are same

Comment: for your second question, they are not the same. `window.location` is an object and `window.location.href` a string. It's a JS feature that when `window.location` is used where a string is needed, the function `window.location.toString()` is called by default, and this function returns `href` property (depends on the usage context)

Comment: Got it. Essentially they have the same functionanlity.

Answer (score -1):

Like MDN documentation,

`location.href` is used when you want to redirect and keep the history, it's identical to when users click on link on websites.

`location.replace` is used when you want to redirect but not keep the history.

`window.location` is different from `window.location.href`. window.location is an object while window.location.href is a string. window.location.href is a child element of window.location object

Comment: You're just repeating the facts already stated in the question which is asking for examples of scenarios when you would want to keep the history or not.

Comment: One simple example to use `location.replace` is when you want to redirect to login page and wish to let users not be able to click back to see page that requires login.

location.href is used more often then `location.replace`

Comment: That would require that you use `location.replace` for every bit of navigation performed while logged in. This would break the back button. It's a terrible idea. Set proper caching rules with HTTP instead.

Comment: @Quentin , it was just an example to see what's different between location.href and location.replace. In the real world app, this login specific case is handle from server side.

The original question was NOT about specific case with a real code snippet. It was just asking for explanation so I thought a sample case would be enough to answer the question.

Comment: No. The question is very specifically asking "what are the scenarios when I should be doing this?"

Comment: @Quentin , I think an example would be enough to understand so the questioner has an idea of how to use it. It'd be impossible to list down all the scenarios in this specific case

Also my answer does clarify that `window.location` and `window.location.href` are NOT the same.

Comment: That's why we have an "Off-topc, too broad" option. Stackoverflow is designed to find solutions for problems, not to find problems for solutions.